# Understanding the verb 意識してくれて

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

So MC is a onsen date with his quasi girlfriend and he tells her this:

だから急なデートの誘いにも乗ってくれた

That's why you accept the proposition of a date

だめだって言ってるけど本心は違って

You say it's no good/I don't want to be with you, etc, but it's not your true opinion

俺と二人きりで意識してくれてるんですよ

This is the part I'm not sure. What is this use of 意識してくれて? I want to say it's like "You were consciousness of being just the two of us", but I don't understand this use of  意識してくれて

Comment: してくれる/してくれている means he likes her emotion (意識する - thinking about their relationship) and express thankfulness for her considering him as such existence.

Comment: Do you understand 意識する? Do you understand くれる as a modifier? Grammatically, are you familiar with te-form? Put it together from parts.

Answer (score 1):

1. 俺と二人きりで意識してるんですよ。
   It's just the two of us with me, and she's conscious of it.
2. 俺と二人きりで意識して**くれて**るんですよ。
   It's just the two of us with me, and *(thankfully)* she's conscious of it.

Your sentence (Sentence 2) is the same as Sentence 1 but くれる is attached. 意識する is "to be conscious", and 意識してる is its te(i)ru form. くれる after a te-form indicates her action ("being conscious") is beneficial to the subject.